# Jasminerice with knockout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, knockout.js, coffeescript, jasmine

I can use Jasminerice (https://github.com/bradphelan/jasminerice) to test a class like:

```
class @Survey
  constructor: (id) ->
    @id = id
```

With the test:

```
#= require survey
describe "Survey", ->
  it "has id of one", ->
    v = new Survey(1)
    expect(v.id).toEqual(1)
```

It works like that, but I can't add the "ko" variable without getting an undefined for "ko". I tried adding `#= require knockout` but it says it can't find the file (I load knockout from a cdn).

How can I add a script source tag for knockout so jasminerice can load it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to add the `knockout-rails` gem but don't add the require on the `application.js`. That way you can still use the knockout js file from the cdn and be able to add the `#= require knockout` to the file `spec.js.coffee`